# Service Broker not supported in Azure SQL managed instance?

Tags: sql-server, service-broker, azure-sql-managed-instance

Even Service Broker seems to be available for Azure SQL managed instance, I was able to activate it, when I run:

```
CREATE QUEUE ExpenseQueue;
```

, I get the error:

> Statement 'CREATE QUEUE' is not supported in this version of SQL
> Server.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you're on [Azure SQL Managed Instance](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/products/azure-sql/managed-instance/)? CREATE QUEUE is not available on other services such as [Azure SQL Database](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/products/azure-sql/database/).

Comment: What's the output of `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition');`? If it's not 8 then it's not Azure SQL Managed Instance. Ref: [SERVERPROPERTY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/serverproperty-transact-sql)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, EngineEdition is 5. Veeerry strange, indeed!

Comment: Looks like it’s _not_ managed instance. So how did you configure and activate service broker before you got to the CREATE QUEUE step?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the Azure SQL wasn't a managed instance.
Everything worked normal after setting up a managed instance.